# Swift 3 URLSession Authentication on IBM Domino server

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, lotus-domino

I am a beginner in iOS development. I want to access some data from IBM Domino server with authentication. The code can only give back the server's login page. Anyone know what's wrong? (and sorry for my english)

Here is my code to get data:

```
class URLSessionTest: NSObject, URLSessionDelegate {

let user = "myUser"
let password = "myPwd"
let url = URL.init(string: "https://www.example.com/Test.nsf/0/91182C6C9EEE0414C12580A300312D1A?Opendocument")


func getData() {
    var request = URLRequest.init(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.timeoutInterval = 30.0
    let parameters = ["Username": user, "Password": password] as Dictionary<String, String>
    do {
        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)
    } catch let error {
        print("request serialization error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print ("dataTask error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }
        if let myresponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            print ("dataTask response: \(myresponse)")
            myresponse.statusCode
        }
        let myval = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
        print("dataTask data: \(myval)")
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

And the delegates:

```
open func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Swift.Void){
    print ("challenge \(challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod)")
    var disposition: URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition = .useCredential
    var credential:URLCredential?
    let defaultCredential = URLCredential(user: user, password: password, persistence: URLCredential.Persistence.none)
    if challenge.previousFailureCount > 0 {
        print ("cancel authentication challenge")
        disposition = .cancelAuthenticationChallenge
        credential = nil
    } else if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust {
        print ("Server Trust")
        credential = URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!)

        if (credential != nil) {
            print ("Use credential")
            disposition = .useCredential
        }
        else{
            print ("perform default handling")
            disposition = .performDefaultHandling
            credential = defaultCredential
        }
    }
    else if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate {
        print ("client certificate")
    }
    else if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic {
        print ("Basic authentication")
    }
    else{
        disposition = .cancelAuthenticationChallenge
        credential = nil
    }
    if credential != nil { challenge.sender!.use(credential!, for: challenge)}
    completionHandler(disposition, credential);
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    print ("URLSessionTask didReceive")
    let credential = URLCredential(user: user, password: password, persistence: URLCredential.Persistence.forSession)
    challenge.sender?.use(credential, for: challenge)
    completionHandler(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential,credential)
}
```

Here is the code's output:

```
challenge NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust
Server Trust
Use credential
dataTask response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x610000031780> { URL: https://www.example.com/Test.nsf/0/91182C6C9EEE0414C12580A300312D1A?Opendocument } { status code: 200, headers {
"Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
"Content-Length" = 5949;
"Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
Date = "Sun, 12 Feb 2017 19:14:19 GMT";
Expires = "Tue, 01 Jan 1980 06:00:00 GMT";
Server = "Lotus-Domino";
"Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=0";} }
```

Comment: My guess is that your code expects basic authentication. Check what authentication method the Domino server is set to use for the domain in question

Comment: It seems an IBM-specific problem. I tried to access IBM Websphere Portal and gave similar results, such as IBM Domino. However, I tested to login a Microsoft SharePoint site, it was successful.

Comment: The IBM Domino and IBM Websphere server might have been set up to use LTPA for authentication. This can explain your issue. So you most likely need to change the authentication method for the site on the IBM Domino server to basis authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on @Per Henrik Lausten's comment, Domino servers provide a way to bypass session authentication and allow basic authentication for URLs that access a specific application.  The method is described in [this IBM technote](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_8.0.1/com.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc/DOC/H_OVERRIDING_SESSION_AUTHENTICATION_8847_STEPS.html). This is a better alternative than opening up the entire site to basic authentication. I see that you are using https, which is good, but the properties on the NSF file(s) that you are accessing should also be set to require https connections if they aren't already set that way.

Comment: Well, finally remain in the basic authentication, it really works. Thanks!

Comment: Since it works, please consider up-voting and accepting my answer.